# mbp Ubuntu 14.04.3 mouse/trackpad scrolling

Tags: 14.04, macbook-pro, mouse-scroll, magic-mouse, magic-trackpad

I installed Ubuntu on my mbp (dual boot w el capitan via rEFind) and I'm not getting scrolling by default nor do I see it in **Mouse & Trackpad** How can I get mouse scrolling working again?

*Notes:*

**$ lsb_release -a**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

**$ xinput; dmesg | grep pnp; uname -r**

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth USB Host Controller  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
[    0.364005] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.364497] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.364528] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs APP000b (active)
[    0.364766] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 6 devices
3.19.0-49-generic
```

**$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mtrack**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-mtrack : Depends: xorg-input-abi-20
                             Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.14.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to upgrade to at least 15.10. Starting with the 4.2 Linux kernel support for this newest type of trackpad from Apple was added. Before then you'd need to compile and install your own kernel module for it. Support for it is pretty good but overly sensitive in my opinion. When I hover my fingers just above the trackpad it registers activity. In OS X however, I have to actually touch it before it registers are activity.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some traction by first checking `synclient -l` to see if VertTwoFingerScroll is set to 0 and, if so, you can try switching it on with `synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1`

Comment: `synclient -l` gives me `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`

Comment: you may need to install one of the following packages: xf86-input-synaptics, libsynaptics, or xserver-xorg-input-synaptics